# Windows path handling library

Tags: c++, windows-8

I searched for some path handling functions for windows and I came up with these -> [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Now because it suggests to use the safer ones, I opted for those but I now realized they are windows8 only.
My current machine is windows 8 but I want to support at least windows 7.
I find it very strange though that some essential functions like these are win8 only; all the other functions I used until now (string handling functions for example) had a safer version (the XXX_s version) included in the standard libraries.   Maybe is not a big deal but, is there any alternative I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not an alternative you are missing.

The functions you found served well for many years, but the bar raises on security issues, and newer versions were recently added to reduce the chance of a bad call leading to a buffer overrun.  Generally, new APIs like this are not back-ported to older versions of the OS.

Comment: Thanks, I think for my project the older ones are more than enough.